# Convert object (which is a List<T>) to List<object>

Tags: c#

The method I am overriding has the following signature.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
```

The object that is passed in is a List but the the list type is unknown. It could be `List<string>` or `List<int>`.

I need to cast this into a `List<object>`. I've tried

```
if (!(value is IList temp))
{
    return false;
}

List<object> list = temp.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

which sort of works, but it filters out any null values, presumably because they are not `OfType<object>`

So what's the best way of doing this?

Comment: What is your motive behind doing this. May be a better way exists.

Comment: Have you tried `temp.Cast<object>().ToList()`?

Comment: Why not just `(List<object>)temp`? BTW if it has null values, it can't be a `List<int>`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey because it will not compile)

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KsbBVW

Comment: You can't just cast a `List<SomeType>` to a `List<object>` because then you could write `var dogs = new List<Dog> { Rover, Ruff };` then `var objs = (List<object>) dogs;` and finally `objs.Add(new Cat());`. Suddenly you the variable `dogs` typed as containing a list of `Dogs`, but that also contains a `Cat`

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled - That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> temp.OfType().ToList();

`OfType` checks if the element is of the required type, and if so it puts it in a new temporary list.

<strike>What you're asking is simply a cast, since every instance in C# is an `object`: `(List<object>)temp`.</strike> Edit: apparently covariance doesn't work here.

There's absolutely no reason to do this though, you can simply enumerate it as it is: `foreach(var obj in (IList)temp)`. All collections implement the `IList` non-generic interface.

Comment: That's a working solution.

I also needed to use the .All() method which List provides, but IList doesn't. So @ZoharPeled suggestion of temp.Cast<object>().ToList() is actually better for me

Comment: `IList` doesn't provide `All`, but Linq does, and that works on every `IEnumberable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. Cast it accordingly if that's what you need!

Answer (score 0):

If the input is either `List<int>` or `List<string>` and nothing else, then I think the best approach is to check specifically for these types. So something like:

```
List<object> list ;
if (value is List<int> listOfInts) 
{
   list = listOfInts.Cast<object>().ToList();
} 
else if (value is List<string> listOfStrings) 
{
   list = listOfStrings.Cast<object>().ToList();
} 
else 
{
   throw new ArgumentException(...);
}
```

This might seem redundant, but it might save you a lot of headache down the line, since you will catch if someone passes a `List<SomethingElse>` or even a `List<object>` which would be illegal according to your specification.

Comment: Unfortunately the list  type is unknown. List<int> and List<string> were just two examples of what he list could be. This is being used in a custom validation attribute. That attribute could be applied to a List<anything>